# Should pump from sump run continuously

Tags: fish, aquarium, saltwater

I was recently given an aquarium that includes a sump. I managed to get it setup but the pump is rather loud. Should the pump be running at all times or only at certain times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be running continuously. Normally the sump is where the filtration and heating/cooling is located, so running it only part time would create problems for the main tank.

Is the pump itself loud, or is the overflow into the pump what's making the noise?

Comment: Its the pump itself. I brought another one yesterday thats not as loud.

Comment: Also, the water falling into the sump aerates it.